# How to change extension of file on run time in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a project and I want to show two links to download same file but with different extensions, first link download the file with actual extension and another link download the file with changed extension. Like I have a 1.txt file first link is to download 1.txt file and I want another link to download 1.docx file using ruby on rails.

First link works properly which downloads actual file and I have created a method for second link.

```
def downloaddocxfile
      require 'fileutils'
      Dir.glob(params[:file]).each do |f|
         if File.extname(f) != '.docx'
            FileUtils.cp f, "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.docx"
            send_file "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.docx"
            # system("rm -rf #{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.docx")
         else   
            send_file "#{params[:file]}"
         end
      end
   end
```

This method create a copy of original file and change the extension to .docx.

I don't want to show two files with different extensions in the list of files. So I want to remove that file which is created with .docx  extension once it is downloaded. So, How can I do that?

Comment: [`send_file`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) allows you to specify a filename, there's no need to actually rename the file in your file system.

Comment: BTW, renaming the extension from `txt` to `docx` won't change the file format.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your reply but I am try to change the extension of file not the base name of the file .

Comment: The `:filename` option specifies the full filename, including the extension.

Comment: @Stefan Can you please share the exact code that will help me to solve this issue

Comment: Here's an example: `send_file('x.foo', filename: 'y.bar')` would send the file `x.foo` under the name `y.bar` to the browser. Most browsers will then save the file as `y.bar`.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks it works!!! You can post this as an answer then I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`send_file`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) allows you to specify a filename via the `:filename` option.

Assuming that there's a file `x.foo` on your server, then:

```
send_file('x.foo', filename: 'y.bar')
```

would send the file `x.foo` under the name `y.bar` to the browser.

It's up to the browser to use the suggested name, but most browsers will save the file as `y.bar`.

Comment: Is there any way to update the contents of y.bar file at run time.

Comment: @VarinderSohal probably plenty of ways, but that is beyond the scope of your question. Post a new question regarding your follow-up problem.

Comment: I have posted a new question so can you check please ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655202/how-to-update-a-content-in-new-created-file-by-using-send-file-with-different-ex