# How to update a content in new created file by using send_file with different extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on project where I was need to change the extension of file and download that file with changed extension. I did with following code.

```
send_file('x.foo', filename: 'y.bar')
```

Actual file is `x.foo` and I created `y.bar` file with different extension . Now I want to update content in `y.bar` on run time then I will download that file with different extension and with updated content. How can i do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send_file` doesn't write the file itself. Instead it passes the filename back to web server which then performs the actual writing (so your Rails app has less load).

In order to accomplish your goal, you could read the file, apply the changes in-memory and then use [`send_data`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) to write the data to the client:

```
buffer = File.read('x.foo')
buffer = apply_changes(buffer)
send_data(buffer, filename: 'y.bar')
```

Or you could write the changes to a new file and take advantage of `send_file`:

```
unless File.exist?('y.bar')
  buffer = File.read('x.foo')
  buffer = apply_changes(buffer)
  File.write('y.bar', buffer)
end
send_file('y.bar')
```